# Getting Error code 2068 Load Data Local Infile file request rejected due to restrictions on access in MySql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I edited my.ini config file also. I edited Under the client section and mysqld section following

```
[client]
loose-local-infile=1

[mysqld]
local_infile=1
```

Still doesn't work. following code giving me error (Error code 2068)

```
load data local infile 'C:\Users\kiran\Desktop\Simplilearn Data Analytics\SQL\ProjectSolutionPDF\DataSetAirCargoAnalysis\customer.csv'
into table customer
fields terminated by ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;
```